# MySQL using Aliases

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I have the following syntactically incorrect query with aliases in_Degree and out_degree:

```
insert into userData
select user_name, 
      (select COUNT(*) from tweets where rt_user_name = u.USER_NAME)in_degree,
      (select COUNT(*) from tweets where source_user_name = u.user_name)out_degree, 
      in_degree + out_degree(freq)
   from users u
```

The problem in the query is the the 4th item in the select list aliased as freq. I want the 4th item to have the value in_degree + out_degree. The brute force extremely slow solution would be to copy and past both subqueries and add them.

1. How can I make this fast and as simple as in_degree + out_degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
 insert into userData
 select user_name,
   in_degree,
   out_degree,
   in_degree + out_degree
 from
 (
   select user_name, 
    (select COUNT(*) from tweets where rt_user_name = u.USER_NAME)in_degree,
    (select COUNT(*) from tweets where source_user_name = u.user_name)out_degree
   from users u
 ) src
```

Or you might be able to use:

```
insert into userData
select user_name,
  count(distinct in_t.*) in_degree,
  count(distinct out_t.*) out_degree,
  count(distinct in_t.*) + count(distinct out_t.*)
from users u
left join tweets in_t
  on u.USER_NAME = in_t.rt_user_name
left join tweets out_t
  on u.USER_NAME = out_t.source_user_name
 group by u.user_name
```

Comment: The second query would need a `GROUP BY u.USER_NAME` to work and a `DISTINCT` inside the counts to avoid the multiple counts created by the cartesian product.

Comment: I really like the subquery method

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: take care with those correlated subqueries, they can eat your lunch (performance wise) with large sets. Quite often, joining inline views will give better performance. On small sets, it's hard to see any performance difference. It's when the number of rows get huge that the performance differences are amplified.

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, you can't reference the aliases given in that select list, except in a HAVING clause or an ORDER BY clause.

One option is to use your query as an "inline view", and write a wrapper query around that.

- remove the 4th (invalid) expression from the select list in your query,
- wrap your query in a set of parens
- follow the closing paren with an alias (e.g.) s
- write a query around that, referencing the inline view as if it were a table
- the select list on the outer query can reference the "aliases" defined in the inline view.

However, if you want to make this "fast", you might consider (as an option) taking an entirely different tack.  Rather than using correlated subqueries to get the count for each individal user, you could get the counts for all users, and then use LEFT JOIN operator, e.g.

```
SELECT u.user_name
     , IFNULL(i.cnt,0) AS in_degree
     , IFNULL(o.cnt,0) AS out_degree
     , IFNULL(i.cnt,0)+IFNULL(o.cnt,0) AS freq
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT rt_user_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tweets 
        GROUP BY rt_user_name) i
    ON i.rt_user_name = u.user_name
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT source_user_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tweets 
        GROUP BY source_user_name) o
    ON o.source_user_name = u.user_name
```

Comment: @Sir Rufo: with indexes `ON tweets(rt_user_name)`, `ON tweets(source_user_name)` and `ON users(user_name)`, this might indeed be the most efficient approach.  Those correlated subqueries can eat your lunch (performance wise) for a large number of rows from the `users` table.  If the query was only looking at a small number of rows from the users table, then the correlated subqueries would probably be faster.

Comment: i should have bolded "in this case" -> all users. Talking about index should also include to use a user id (INT/BIGINT) instead of user_name (characters) to speed up performance and decrease memory consumption :o)

Comment: Correct you are again, sir, Sir Rufo.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
insert into userData
  SELECT T.user_name,
       T.in_degree,
       T.out_degree,
       (T.in_degree + T.out_degree) as freq
   FROM (SELECT user_name, 
          (select COUNT(*) from tweets where rt_user_name = u.USER_NAME) as in_degree,
          (select COUNT(*) from tweets where source_user_name = u.user_name) as out_degree      
           FROM users u) T
```

Answer (score 0):

In a fast way, I would do something like:

```
insert into userData
select 
    TMP.user_name,
    TMP.in_degree,
    TMP.out_degree,
    (TMP.in_degree + TMP.out_degree) degreeSum
from(
    select user_name, 
        (select COUNT(*) from tweets where rt_user_name = u.USER_NAME)in_degree,
        (select COUNT(*) from tweets where source_user_name = u.user_name)out_degree
    from users u
) TMP
```